# Hidding button when selecting table row

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So im trying to hide a button in TableView.m and the button is declared in ViewController.h whenever I make a selection in `DidSelectRowAtIndex` which is equal to the second row.

My code:

**TableView.m:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [popoverSpending dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(spendingButtonText:)]) {
        [self.delegate spendingButtonText:cell.textLabel.text];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        NSLog(@"2");
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
        appDelegate.vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];

        appDelegate.vc.button1.hidden = TRUE;

    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I select the second row it traces 2, which is good cause of `NSLog(@"2");`. However my button named **button1** is still visible. My TableView.m is a class of ViewController. Tell me if you need to see more code and ill edit.

Comment: You are creating new instance of ViewController class. just remove appDelegate.vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

When you do this: `appDelegate.vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];`, it creates a *new* instance of `ViewController` class. What you want is the *existing* instance of that class that is being displayed right now. Just remove that line and set `appDelegate.vc.button1.hidden = TRUE` directly.